# Difficult Improper Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

> Evaluate the improper integral
>   $$\int_0^\infty\frac{-38x}{(2x^2+9)(3x^2+4)} dx $$

I thought about doing this through partial fractions decomposition. 
However, when I tried, I got some really awful numbers like $\dfrac{114}{19}$.
Did I make a mistake somewhere in my math, or is there an easier method to solving this?
Also, this is a multiple choice question and the answers all involve $\ln$. Is that another indicator that the best method is partial fractions?

Comment: Substitute $u=x^2$ and then the partial fractions is easy.

Comment: @TedShifrin but then, wouldn't that leave me with a square root u in the numerator?

Comment: No, the derivative is gonna save you @Chrysanthemum

Comment: What's so terrible about $\frac{114}{19}$?

Comment: @JavierBadia Write the digit three times, one after the other, and you have a number that some people consider evil.

Comment: nope. $u = x^2 \rightarrow du = 2x$ so numerator is $-19\,du$

Comment: Substitution is a good start. But the partial fraction expression for the original form turns out to be nice too.

Answer (score 4):

Substituting $u=x^2$,
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{-38x}{(2x^2+9)(3x^2+4)} dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{-19}{(2u+9)(3u+4)} du$$

Now,

$$\frac{-19}{(2u+9)(3u+4)}=\frac{2}{2u+9}-\frac{3}{3u+4}$$

Thus

$$I=\lim_{L\rightarrow\infty}\left[ \log(2u+9) - \log(3u+4)\right|_0^L=\left(\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty} \log(2u+9)-\log(3u+4) \right) -2\log(3/2)$$

Further

$$\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty} \log(2u+9)-\log(3u+4)=\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty} \log\frac{2u+9}{3u+4}=\log\frac{2}{3}=-\log\frac{3}{2}$$

Therefore,

$$I=-3\log\frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: you should replace u with L in the limit

Comment: Yes typo, thank you. @DylanDang

Comment: Excellent answer (+1). At the very end you could write $I=3log\frac{2}{3}$